# What does "angle of attack 100%" mean in Apollo abort rules?

Tags: apollo-program, saturn-v, abort

In [Apollo Mission Rules](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/A11MissRules.pdf) and [Saturn V Flight Manuals](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap12fj/pdf/a12_sa507-flightmanual.pdf), I have seen the following abort rules:

[image]

I understand what most of this means -- if the launch vehicle begins turning at more than 4 degrees per second, abort is indicated, and so on.

However, in the Max Q region (50 seconds to 2 minutes after launch, so really the ["high Q"](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/15456/how-long-does-max-q-last) region), an angle of attack of "100%" is grounds for abort. I'm used to [angle of attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_attack) meaning the angle between the vehicle's long axis and the airstream, and given in degrees, not in percentage.

**How should I interpret "Angle of Attack (Q α) = 100%" in this document?**

Comment: It's quite common to mesure slopes in %. In this case it would mean for 1m traveled sideways, 1m traveled up (ie 45 degrees inclination)

Comment: I don't think that's it @Antzi, it's not a slope, in this case 100% would mean a 90 degree angle to the relative airflow. I don't think that would be possible 50 seconds after liftoff, the spacecraft would have disintegrated before it could reach it. My guess is that 100% is actually in this case the maximum aerodynamic pressure the spacecraft could tolerate as a result of having an angle of attack, which was supposed to be 0 deg at all times.

Comment: 100% would be 45º (1:1 rise:run), not 90º, but you're right, there's no way the abort limit would be 45º at Max Q.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not angle of attack that the rule refers to. It is Q-alpha which is the *dynamic pressure times the angle of attack*. The shuttle had pre-calculated Q-alpha and Q-beta structural limits; apparently Apollo did too, and this rule applied when the instantaneous value of Q-alpha reached or exceeded 100% of the pre-calculated structural limit.

Edit:

---

This Q-alpha value was actually displayed to the crew on a meter. (On orbit the meter served as the Service Propulsion System chamber pressure meter.)
The description of the value shown on the meter is:

> the qa display is a pitch and yaw vector summed
>   angle-of-attack/dynamic pressure product (qa). It is expressed in
>   percentage of total pressure for predicted launch vehicle breakup
>   (abort limit equals 100%).

[image]
[image]

References

[Orbiter simulator graphics for high-res closeup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cK2mAFYgKeE)

[Saturn V Flight Manual SA-503 for description and panel image](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwitsKb_0erbAhUSUa0KHY7-DMsQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhistory.nasa.gov%2Fafj%2Fap08fj%2Fpdf%2Fsa503-flightmanual.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2Eq5oQ-K-aAo6oHJKi4PlM)

End Edit

---

Additional info:

The shuttle rules were shown as plots of Q-alpha versus Q-beta, indexed by Mach number. The plots had the strange name of "squatcheloids".

Here is a sample Shuttle squatcheloid showing the Q-alpha and Q-beta limits at a given Mach number.

[image]

[Source of image](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19820007233.pdf&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjnwqzUgujbAhUCXa0KHRJOCLkQFggLMAA&usg=AOvVaw2qpLeE1L2JgZm9pCAuAJDZ)

Comment: Okay, but "this rule applied when 100% of the limit had been reached" seems tautological -- the mission rule says the limit is 100% of the limit. I assume the actual Q-alpha information is in some other doc somewhere, but this still seems weird.

Comment: I assume the controller had a display showing the % limit reached. Abort at 100% or above. ln other words, 50% of the structural limit is ok but above 100% of the limit things are gonna break. Makes perfect sense to me but it's the world I came from.

Comment: Will try a rewrite.

Comment: That helps a bit, thanks. I guess if the only direct application of Q-alpha is the abort limit it makes sense to track it a %age of the limit since it otherwise has somewhat odd units.

Comment: For shuttle these limits were primarily used in testing trajectory designs prelaunch, not for aborts, I was surprised to learn that Apollo used them that way.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I found support for my speculations in the AS-503 flight manual, edited answer.

Comment: Great find! Interesting/terrifying that the abort limit is equal to the predicted structural failure value -- if you haven't fallen apart yet, try to keep going!

Comment: The shuttle limits were "knocked down" for uncertainties.  Hopefully Apollo's were too.

Comment: I assume Q-beta is dynamic pressure times sideslip angle? And I assume STS had to consider Q-alpha and Q-beta separately because of the significant differences in vertical and horizontal geometry of the shuttle stack, while the Saturn V could use a single "pitch and yaw vector summed angle-of-attack" figure because it was rotationally symmetrical?

Comment: Right about q-beta. I don't know any more about Apollo limits than what I wrote here.

Comment: Any units given for those squatcheloid plots?

Comment: IIRC for DOLILU on shuttle it was psf-deg. Still away from home, can confirm  later.

Comment: @RussellBorogove back home and checked my logs from the STS-114 launch. The units for shuttle were indeed pounds-force per square foot times degrees.