# What was the actual Q-alpha limit for Saturn/Apollo launches, and what was the typical max Q-alpha?

Tags: apollo-program, aerodynamics, abort, max-q

Organic Marble's [answer to a previous question](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/28041/195) about Apollo abort limits clarified that the figure of concern was the *product* of dynamic pressure (Q) and angle of attack (alpha), with the 100% level apparently being the expected structural-breakup limit of the launcher.

**What is the actual limit value for Qɑ for the Saturn V/Apollo stack?**

**What was the maximum Qɑ reached in nominal launches?**

I'm looking for a value in psi•degrees or kPa•radians or some dimensionally equivalent pressure-times-angle units, not a normalized percentage-of-abort-limit value. Answers for other launchers are of interest as well.

I'm curious because the guidance equations in my launch simulator do produce some significant angle-of-attack, and I want to know if the trajectories I'm flying would be likely to wreck a Saturn V.

Answer (score 6):

I have not yet found the abort limit figure.

According to [Saturn V AS-507 "G" Mission Launch Vehicle Operational Flight Trajectory - September Launch Month](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap12fj/pdf/as-507-planned-lv-flight-traj-19700072469.pdf) (a trajectory planning document for Apollo 12), the peak Qɑ for a nominal flight would be between 18 and 22 kNº/m^2 (= kPaº):

[image: Graph of Q-alpha product versus mission time for pre-launch simulation of Apollo 12. Three tracks are shown corresponding to three different launch azimuths (presumably for three different launch dates). The tracks peak sharply around T = 72 seconds at approximately 18.5, 20.0, and 21.5 thousand newton degrees per meter squared.]

Comment: I'm kinda stunned that it's in metric units!

Answer (score 4):

Edit: I stumbled upon the limit.

> The maximum angle-of-attack
> dynamic pressure sensed by a redundant Q-ball
> mounted atop the escape tower was 0.28 N/cm2 (0.4 psid) between 89 and 91 seconds. This pressure was only 12.5 percent of **the EDS abort limit of 2.2 N/cm2**  (3.2 psid).

Source: [Saturn V Launch Vehicle Flight Evaluation AS-506](https://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/Documents/lvfea-AS506-Apollo11.pdf) page 15-1

Comment: Good find! That helps me a lot. Unfortunately my max payload Saturn INT-21 sim run is hitting 44 kPaº, which is neither definitely over-limit nor definitely under-limit. XD

Comment: @RussellBorogove You don't simulate any winds, do you? If not, then your alphas / betas are probably too big by a {handwaving} amount.  Cause a good wind would push you over the limit.

Comment: That document you linked in your answer has the mean winds in it. Try adding them into your sim and see what happens. Figure 3-81 and subs.

Comment: "just add wind to your sim", he said breezily

Comment: I mean, I'm sure you're right, it's just a pretty major factor that I don't have a good handle on how to implement.

Comment: You could have a lookup table of the wind speed vs altitude - it looks like they only applied it to head/tail, no side wind - then modify alpha by the wind velocity component. The wind is basically just going to change alpha a little and therefore change q*alpha.

Comment: Huh, weird. If I add wind at all I'm doing it in all directions, heh.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I came across the actual answer.

Comment: Thats a pressure (Q) figure, not a pressure•angle, isn't it?

Comment: I think they screwed up on the metric units. First sentence of the quote says 'angle of attack dynamic pressure' and the English units have a 'd' in them.