Shuttle dance bank angle timeline
I'm trying to see how much capacity the Shuttle had for reducing reentry temperatures by adjusting trajectory.
So far, I've only been told then the Shuttle banks up to 80° during reentry. But is that constant? Or do they use different angles at different times?
Shuttle reentry maximum G-force is 1.7. But I don't know when that is experienced. If we assume that it is experienced at 5.5km/s, when gravity is at 0.5g, then at a lift to drag ratio of 1 that corresponds to just 67°. But like I said, I don't know the actual angle, and I would expect it to be lower.

I don't think your goal in the first sentence is on target (see CAIB Report Appendix D-13 Paragraph 4.8). But I can answer the actual questions in your post.
Since STS-001 was a test flight, there is a ton of detailed information available on its entry trajectory.
Here are the aero angles during entry: Roll, Yaw, and Pitch

And here are the body accelerations during entry: X, Y, and Z

Source: Reconstruction of the first space shuttle entry trajectory

There's also a useful "typical" graph in this previous answer of yours: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/31869/1342

All I see is Appendix D. There is no 13, nevermind a paragraph 4.8

@AbdullahisnotanAmalekite Paragraph 4.8 is on the 17th page of the pdf linked in the answer.
